# how to use an intentdefinition file in objective c-swift bridged project?

Tags: objective-c, swift, bridging-header, sirishortcuts

I am having an app which is developed in objective c.
Now I want to integrate that app with Siri Shortcuts using swift.
I am using bridging for that.

So now issue is: when my app is getting compiled intentdefinition file for my app is generating Objective C runtime classes (i.e. ".h" and ".m" classes) and intent targets are generating swift runtime classes (i.e. ".swift" class).

So when I am creating a file, that use both targets (i.e. my app as well as intents target), I am getting an error:

> Use of undeclared type

Comment: You will get a useful answer much sooner if you come up with a complete small example that shows the problem and is expected to compile (of course, it won't because of the error you mentioned).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

project settings -> select target -> Build Settings -> Precompile Bridging Header

set this to **NO**